# Polish signs in verbatim beamer envir

Tags: verbatim

I would like to get polish signs in the verbatim environment for the beamer document type, e.g.

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Napis- funkcja print}

\begin{block}{Przyk\l ad}
\begin{verbatim}
>>> 'Oto napis\n w dwóch linijkach.'
>>> print 'Oto napis\n w dwóch linijkach.'
\end{verbatim}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
```

when I compile it I get 'dwch' instead of dwóch. Obviously I cannot use dw\'och as I would do outside the verbatim env. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you have forgotten to specify an input encoding (see package `inputenc`). Please, complete the example, for example, what is `\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your file in UTF-8

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Napis- funkcja print}

\begin{block}{Przykład}
\begin{verbatim}
>>> 'Oto napiś w dwóch linijkach.'
>>> print 'Oto napiś w dwóch linijkach.'
\end{verbatim}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]